# "IP-Passthrough" OpenVPN configuration

Tags: routing, openvpn

I want to create a VPN configuration that allows a client of a OpenVPN server to use the public IP of the server, as if it was its own IP, connected to the IP.

Here is the network layout right now:

```
                                     +---------------------------------------------------+
                                     |  Server machine (Linux)                           |
                                     |                                                   |
                                     |                                                   |
                                     |                                                   |
                    Data center----->O<--eth0-----------+                                |
                                     |  |79.102.91.184  |                                |
                                     |  |67.248.62.166  |                                |
                                     |  |94.187.137.76  |                                |
                                     |  |189.180.86.216 |                                |
                                     |  |219.167.189.118|                                |
                                     |  +---------------+                                |
                                     |                                                   |
                                     +---------------------------------------------------+

          +------------------------------------------+       +---------------------------+
          |  Router with NAT                         |       |  Client machine (Linux)   |
          |                  NAT                     |       |                           |
          |               +--------+                 |       |                           |
DSL to    |               |        |                 |  LAN  |                           |
Internet->O<---eth0-------+-+    +-+---------eth1-+->O<----->O<---eth0----------------+  |
          |  |24.174.216.166|    |192.168.2.1/24  |  |       |  |192.168.2.10/24      |  |
          |  |              |    |                |  |       |  |Router 192.168.2.1   |  |
          |  |              |    |                |  |       |  |                     |  |
          |  +--------------+    +----------------+  |       |  +---------------------+  |
          |                                          |       |                           |
          +------------------------------------------+       +---------------------------+
```

I want to set up a OpenVPN server on the Server machine. Then, a client should be able to connect to this VPN through the Internet, for example by connecting to `79.102.91.184` (first IP of the server.)

On the client machine, a tap or tun adapter should be created, that has one of the other publicly routable IPs of the server assigned and correctly routed. For example, the client can now communicate with the internet using the IP `67.248.62.166` (and the server can not be reached under this IP anymore).

How can I set up OpenVPN in a way that makes this kind of routing scenario possible?

Comment: So, you want to make only one VPN connection to OpenVPN server at one time?

Comment: @AlexanderT Correct, my scenario would be limited to exactly one user per server IP. It would be okay as well to run a OpenVPN instance per user, if that makes the project possible.

Comment: "and the server can not be reached under this IP anymore": Please elaborate.

Comment: @gf_ Previously, the server machine was reachable under the IP *x*. Now, the client of the VPN can be reached directly using this IP, not the server - the client is supposed to communicate as if it was natively connected to the internet using this public IP. Does this clarify it?

Comment: Does the client needs to address the new IP? Or is it enough if the client is seen from the internet as the new address? I mean, does the client want to bind to the new address explicitly (instead of binding to 0.0.0.0)?

Comment: @Lacek Yes, if that was possible, it would be ideal. I do want to have direct communications access, so the client receives packages from the original IP that contacted the passed-through IP.

Comment: Think of a VPN as if it is a cable connected to its own interface on the client machine to the internal network where it terminates. The VPN link should either have its own network for the link, or it should be a transparent link, giving the client machine an IP address on the internal network to which the VPN connects. Trying to do anything else will probably not work, be a pain in the butt, and be very fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact behavior you would like to achieve seems impossible. With a VPN in **`TUN`nel** mode you'll always get an internal VPN IP and be behind a NAT towards Internet. While all your traffic seems to originate from the IP address on the other side, it's still shared among other VPN users and doesn't expose the client computer directly to the Internet with that IP.

OpenVPN **bridging** (`TAP` mode) behaves more close to your desired state. You should learn the difference between [bridging and routing](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting), but basically it simulates *link layer* device, giving you an IP address from the other side. You should also learn about OpenVPN [Ethernet Bridging](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/ethernet-bridging.html) as it is useless to copy the whole manual here, but here's a relevant citation (configuration after installing `brigde-utils` & editing/running `bridge-start` script) for further discussion:

> Comment out the lines which says `dev tun` and begins with `server` and replace it instead with:
>
> ```
> dev tap0 
> server-bridge 192.168.8.4 255.255.255.0 192.168.8.128 192.168.8.254
> ```
>
> Now set up the Linux firewall to permit packets to flow freely over
>   the newly created `tap0` and `br0` interfaces:
>
> ```
> iptables -A INPUT -i tap0 -j ACCEPT 
> iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
> iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
> ```

While it is not usual and might not be a good idea, it should be possible to bridge a public network interface similarly as the private `192.168.8.0/24` subnet has been bridged in the example, giving clients IP addresses between `192.168.8.128` and `192.168.8.254`.

**However, it still would have prerequisites that aren't currently met.** You would need to have a public IP address subnet to be bridged (i.e. used for your *VPN client address pool*) instead of these independent IP addresses from here and there.

Comment: Well, one could just assign the server-bridge a `255.255.255.255` subnet, that could work, not?

Comment: The subnet MUST be the actual [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) of the interface to be bridged. Otherwise it won't be able to make _layer 2_ connections to another addresses on the same subnet, including the gateway.

Answer (score 3):

Although this may not answer your question, I think this is the closest you can get. It works as you expect, but for one thing: the client won't have the "external" IP address, for it needs to reside on the server.

Also note that this is not how VPNs should work.

Anyway, here is what you need to do. I'm assuming here that your VPN server has several IP addresses, one of which is reserved for the VPN itself. The rest are to be mapped to clients, so a connected client will be seen as this outer IP address.

1. Ensure all clients have a statically assigned address.
2. SNAT traffic from that IP address to appear to have originated from the "outer" interface.
3. DNAT traffic pointing to the outer interface to the VPN tunnel

### Ensure all clients have a static address

For this, add the following lines to your server-side openvpn config file:

```
client-config-dir clientConfig
ccd-exclusive
```

Create the `clientConfig` directory to the `/etc/openvpn/` directory. This will hold the per-client configuration files. The `ccd-exclusive` option will cause clients to fail if they not have a corresponding client config in the directory specified by `client-config-dir`. Since your setup depends on having an exact mapping of external and VPN IP addresses, every client should have its own config.

iIn the client config directory, create a file named as the common name of the client, that is, the CN field of the certificate or the username, depending on the authentication method you use. The file should contain a simple IP address push, like this:

```
ifconfig-push 192.168.0.5 192.168.0.6
```

Note that every client should have its own /30 network from which the two IP addresses assigned, and the networks should not overlap.

Add the `redirect-gateway` directive to the client-side config file in order to replace the default gateway, like this:

```
redirect-gateway def1
```

After this, the client should have the same IP address no matter when it connects, and will have its default gateway rewritten after connecting.

### Setting up SNAT

For every client, a SNAT rule must be set up like this:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o <device> \
    -s <client_ip> -j SNAT --to <out_ip>
```

where:

- `<device>` is the outbound device (in your case, `eth0`)
- `<client_ip>` is the IP you set up to the client in the previous step (in the above example `192.168.0.5`)
- `<out_ip>` is the IP address which is seen by the servers the clients connects to (e.g. `67.248.62.166` is one such IP in your example)

Also, be sure to set IP forwarding to true (`echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`).

### Setting up DNAT

For every client, you should issue a command like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING \
    -i <device> -d <out_ip> -j DNAT --to <client_ip>
```

The `<device>`, `<out_ip>` and `<client_ip>` parameters are the same as above.

The `iptables` commands described above can be issued if the connection is not active (in fact, the openvpn server needs not running).

### What's left out

This way the connection works in both directions: from the internet, the outer IP address is accessible, and every traffic (both TCP and UDP) will be blindly forwarded to the client. If the client initiates a connection, it will be seen as originating from the VPN server's specified IP address.

This is almost what you wanted.

One thing will not work: the client will not be able to grab the outer interface. In fact, the client won't even be aware of the outside IP address. That is, you won't be able to bind to (for example) `189.180.86.216`. You will, however, be able to use `0.0.0.0`, and this way the client will be accessible through the "outside" IP address.

Also note that you have to assign an IP address for the VPN server. That address can't be used for forwarding every traffic to any of the clients, for obvious reasons.